# Java EE transaction rollback

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have following ejb:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= shopItem.getQuantity(); i++) {
        purchase = new Purchase();
        purchase.setUser(user);
        // a lot of sets
        purchase.setPhoneNumber(order.getPhoneNumber());
        try {
            financeEntityEjb.createPurchase(purchase);
        } catch (NotEnoughFundsException e) {
       throw new NotEnoughFundsExceptionWithRollback(e); // Making in rollable
     }
  }

public void createPurchase(Purchase purchase) throws InputValidationException, NotEnoughFundsException {
    // a lot of calculations
    em.persist(purchase);
    em.flush();
    /* Closing Order */
            purchase.getOrder().setState(Order.State.PURCHASED);
            em.merge(purchase.getOrder());

    }
```

My Exception class:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class NotEnoughFundsExceptionWithRollback extends NotEnoughFundsException {
public NotEnoughFundsExceptionWithRollback() {
    }

    public NotEnoughFundsExceptionWithRollback(Throwable e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public NotEnoughFundsExceptionWithRollback(String message, Throwable e) {
        super(message, e);
    }
}
```

So I have problem that ejb rollbacks all em.persist(purchase); but ignores em.merge(purchase.getOrder());

UPD: Loop is in purchaseEjb. and CreatePurchase method is on financeEjb

Comment: Not sure where the Tx context is started and finished. If the loop is in one EJB and the createPurchase in another it depends on the annotation whether a Tx is started for create or not. In any case I would expect that if em.persist and em.merge are in the same method it should be rolled back both. Could you add a bit more context?

Comment: @wfink, I don't know what to add=(, there are a lot of code, that is not appropriate to my problem

Comment: how are you obtaining the `EntityManager` and what type of EJB are you using.

Comment: @raphaëλ Stateless ejb, and PersistenceContext(unitName = name") private EntityManager em;

Comment: ok, tx. BTW you don't need the `flush` and `merge`, why did you add these?

Comment: @raphaëλ I don't know what is root of the problem and added this one=), this was not in the firstly

Comment: You should remove those calls. Are you saying the INSERT of `Purchase` is rolled-back, but the UPDATE of the `Order` not?

Comment: @raphaëλ ok, I will. Yes, exactly what I mean

Comment: Could you show the `persistence.xml` and what type of database are you using?

Comment: @raphaëλ http://pastebin.com/fLYXx8ip here is xml, I use mysql

Comment: that looks good as well. What type of MySQL engine (for example MyISAM does not support transactions)

Comment: You are really sure that upon the seemingly rollback the order update remains? Can you show the `Purchase -> Order` accociation(s) (field declarations and annotations used)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118208/discussion-between-raphae-and-mondayguy).

Comment: It is essential to understand transactional behaviour of EJB's. If you don't annotate (or use XML) for transactions the default is to start one.  From the EJB specification a persistence access with JPA need to have a transaction (if not there is implicit one created - but this might have issues with consistence)

Comment: @LinuRadu No, sorry plz. I even don't remember

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the code in the for-loop is not within the, or an, ejb (you are not using `this`). In that case most likely the problem is the following

Container managed transaction in EJB last a single method call. Depending on the transactional attributes it ignores, starts or joins a transaction.
The default is *required*, which means the transaction starts on the call to `createPurchase` and ends when the method is finished (tipically a
proxy takes care if this) .

The transaction is rolledback on a `RuntimeException`, when an application exception is throws with `@ApplicationException(rollback = true)` or when
the set-rollback-only-flag has been set.

In your case most likely none of these happen within the transactional context of `createPurchase`. You did not show the code for `NotEnoughFundsException`, but
 i am assuming it is not annoted with `@ApplicationException(rollback = true)`.

Instead you have annotated the `NotEnoughFundsExceptionWithRollback`, which is thrown outside of the transactional context by the client calling the EJB.

If you want the whole loop to be an atomic operation, you need to place that in an transactional context (e.g, using an EJB)

Comment: Whole code is in EJB's, but it is different ejb's), plz check edit